# Switcheroo Control - Launch Using Dedicated Graphic Error on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: 18.10, hybrid-graphics

My laptop has Radeon HD 7400M Graphics Card and Intel HD 3000 and it's running well when i checked via terminal. However, The "**Launch Using Dedicated Graphic Card**" when i click the right button is not there. So i try to reinstall *switcheroo-control* via synaptics package manager and the option "Launch Using Dedicated Graphic Card is available. BUT everytime after i restart the laptop, the option  it's not there and i have to reinstall the switcheroo package T_T. Is there anyone have solutions?